# Memory heap keeps increasing using ag-grid, angular and websocket

Tags: heap-memory, ag-grid-angular

We needed to create a Live Monitor sort of screen that gets the feed through a WebSocket. Angular 11 is used for the UI part. When the page is left on Chrome for a few minutes, the memory heap starts increasing and gradually it increases to a greater extent. After some time, the application will hang and we can't go to another page of the application.
I'm unable to understand the cause of the memory leak, if any.

HTML Code:

```html
<ag-grid-angular #LiveHedgeGrid class="ag-theme-balham" [rowData]="hedgeRowData" [columnDefs]="hedgeColumn" (gridReady)="onLiveHedgeReady($event)" (columnRowGroupChanged)="oncolumnRowGroupChanged($event)" (gridSizeChanged)="onGridSizeChanged($event)"
  [enableCellChangeFlash]="true" [rowBuffer]="10" [debounceVerticalScrollbar]="true" [suppressColumnVirtualisation]="true" [groupIncludeTotalFooter]="true" [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [suppressAggFuncInHeader]="true" [groupDefaultExpanded]="groupDefaultExpanded"
  [domLayout]="domLayout">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

TypeScript Code:

```
websocketCall() {
let socket = new WebSocket(ApiService.webSocketUrl);
socket.onopen = e => {
};
 socket.onmessage = e => {
  let server_message;
  try {
    server_message = JSON.parse(e.data);
    server_message = JSON.parse(server_message);

    if (server_message instanceof Array) {
      this.bindTableValues(server_message);
    } else {
      this.bindTableValues([server_message]);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    this.bindTableValues(server_message);
  }
  // console.log('socket open');
};
socket.onclose = () => {
  //console.log('Web Socket Connection Closed');
};}

 async bindTableValues(server_message) {
await server_message.forEach(element => {
  this.ricData = {};
  let ricPeriod = '';
  let itemsToUpdate = [];
  let data = {};
  let value = 0;

  let ricData = this.ricList[element['RIC']];
  if (ricData) {
    if (ricData['type'] == 'swap') {
      value = element['Fields']['NETCHNG_1'];
      ricPeriod = ricData['disp_name'];
      ricPeriod = ricPeriod.toString().trim().substring(0, ricPeriod.length - 1).toLowerCase();
      if (value) {
        //const itemsToUpdate: any[] = [];
      this.gridApi.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort((rowNode) => {
          if(!rowNode.group) {
            data = rowNode.data;
            if(data['Tenor'] == ricPeriod) {
              data['LivePnL'] = parseFloat(data['DV01']) * value * 100;
              itemsToUpdate.push(data);
            }
          }
        });
        // this.gridApi.applyTransaction({ update: itemsToUpdate })!;
        // this.gridApi.applyTransactionAsync({ update: itemsToUpdate })!;
        this.gridApi.batchUpdateRowData({ update: itemsToUpdate })!;
      };
    }
  };
});}


ngOnDestroy(): void {
try {
  //console.log('Destroy ' + this.socket.readyState);
  // if (this.socket.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
  if (this.socket.readyState === 1) {
    this.socket.close();
  }
  this.getRic.unsubscribe();
  this.getTable.unsubscribe();
}
catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}}
```